# How to print only a specific link in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm still a newbie in Python but I'm trying to make my first little program.
My intention is to print only the link ending with **.m3u8** (if available) istead of printing the whole web page.
The code I'm currently using:

```
import requests
channel1 = requests.get('https://website.tv/user/111111')
print(channel1.content)
print('\n')
channel2 = requests.get('https://website.tv/user/222222')
print(channel2.content)
print('\n')
input('Press Enter to Exit...')
```

The link I'm looking for always has 47 characters in total, and it's always the same model just changing the stream id represented as X:

```
https://website.tv/live/streamidXXXXXXXXX.m3u8
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex for this problem.

**Explanation:**

here in the expression portion .*? means to consider everything and whatever enclosed in \b(expr)\b needs to be present there mandatorily.

For e.g.:

```
import re

link="https://website.tv/live/streamidXXXXXXXXX.m3u8"

p=re.findall(r'.*?\b.m3u8\b',link)
print(p)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['https://website.tv/live/streamidXXXXXXXXX.m3u8']
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to go about this, one that springs to mind which others have touched upon is using **regex** with `findall` that returns back a list of matched urls from our `url_list`.

Another option could also be **BeautifulSoup** but without more information regarding the `html` structure it may not be the best tool here.

**Using Regex**

```
from re import findall
from requests import get


def check_link(response):
    result = findall(
        r'.*?\b.m3u8\b',
        str(response.content),
    )
    return result

def main(url):
    response = get(url)
    if response.ok:
        link_found = check_link(response)
        if link_found:
            print('link {} found at {}'.format(
                    link_found,
                    url,
                ),
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_list = [
        'http://www.test_1.com',
        'http://www.test_2.com',
        'http://www.test_3.com',
    ]
    for url in url_list:
        main(url)

    print("All finished")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will extract all URLs from webpage and filter only those which contain your required keyword ".m3u8"

```
import requests
import re
def get_desired_url(data):
    urls = []
    for url in re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', data):
        if ".m3u8" in url:
            urls.append(url)
    return urls

channel1 = requests.get('https://website.tv/user/111111')
urls = get_desired_url(channel1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly I think you want to use Python's `.split()` string method. If your goal is to take a string like `"https://website.tv/live/streamidXXXXXXXXX.m3u8"` and extract just `"streamidXXXXXXXXX.m3u8"` then you could do that with the following code:

```
web_address = "https://website.tv/live/streamidXXXXXXXXX.m3u8"
specific_file = web_address.split('/')[-1]
print(specific_file)
```

The calling `.split('/')` on the string like that will return a list of strings where each item in the list is a different part of the string (first part being `"https:"`, etc.). The last one of these (index [-1]) will be the file extension you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think this will be robust

```
import re

links=[re.sub('^<[ ]*a[ ]+.*href[ ]*=[ ]*',  '', re.sub('.*>$', '', link) for link in re.findall(r'<[ ]*a[ ]+.*href[ ]*=[]*"http[s]*://.+\.m3u8".*>',channel2.content)]
```